# Rails 4: get list of permitted attributes (strong parameters) from a controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, documentation, strong-parameters

I'm trying to automate some documentation for an API and would like to retrieve the list of attributes listed by `strong_parameters`, as that's really the public face of my API.

What I would like to do:

```
def MyController < ApplicationController
  # ...CRUD actions...

  private
  def my_params
    require(:resource).permit(:first_name, :last_name, :age)
  end
end

MyController.my_params => [:first_name, :last_name, :age]
```

Typically the listing is marked as `private`, so that's the first issue.  I don't want to maintain 2 separate lists of attributes for a resource, so I would really like to access the actual values permitted by the code to keep my automated documentation accurate.

So far it looks like the params listing is not accessible outside the controller.

Comment: Did you ever figure out if this was possible?

Comment: @eggroll: the only solution I could think of is using a public method in the controller that calls the private method; a bit "hacky", but should do the trick.  But other than that I haven't come up with a clean solution :/

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. Unfortunately, for what I'm trying to do, adding a method isn't an option. I was hoping there was some internal Rails way of accessing that list of parameters. It feels like some how there has to be, but maybe not. I'll keep digging. Cheers!