# How to get a list of permitted params for a specific controller action

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, controller, strong-parameters

The title of the questions pretty much describes what I need to do. It is basically the same as this question, which never received an answer:

[Rails 4: get list of permitted attributes (strong parameters) from a controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31686791/rails-4-get-list-of-permitted-attributes-strong-parameters-from-a-controller)

Similar to the example provided in that question, it would be the equivalent to something like this, if it existed:

`account_update_permitted_params = AccountController.permitted_params(:update)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You basically can't do that due to the nature of strong parameters.

What you define in `some_resource_attributes` is meant to filter parameters hash of the request. If you look at the method definition, you will see `params.require(:some_resource).permit..` - it operates on the `params` object, which is only present during a request.

So having such method seems to be of very little use.

If you really want to programatically access your whitelisted attributes in the `some_resource_attributes`, you can go with:

```
class ResourceController < ApplicationController
  LIST = %i(foo bar baz)

  private

  def resource_attributes
    params.require(:resource).permit(*LIST)
  end
end
ResourceController::LIST
#=> [:foo, :bar, :baz]
```

But I dot see a point in this since you can just open controller's code and check it.

Comment: Thanks for the response! I was trying to programmatically access permitted attributes for a controller that I would not be able to add additional code to, such as `LIST` in your example. I see that this is not possible due to, as you state, the params object being present only during the request.